# strtol() incorrectly returns 0

Tags: c, string, sockets, strtol

I am working on a project, and for some reason I am not able to get `strtol()` to convert a `char *` to an integer. I have this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //socket initialization code...

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    char *buffer;
    receivePacket(&sock, &buffer, &addr); //function i have written to receive a packet
    char *temp;
    int times = (int) strtol(buffer, &temp, 10);
}
```

When I run this, times always ends up being 0, and temp returns garbage:

```
(gdb) print buffer
$1 = 0xbefff648 "1"
(gdb) print times
$2 = 0
(gdb) print temp
$3 = 0xbefff648 "H\366\377\276(\207"
```

I don't understand why strtol cannot comprehend what I am giving it.

In `receivePacket`:

```
void receivePacket(int *sock, char **buffer, long *tx, struct sockaddr_in *cliaddr) {
    //socket related code, initializations, etc.
    char temp[10] = { 0 };
    n = recvfrom(*sock, temp, 10, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cliAddr, &clilen);
    *buffer = temp;
}
```

Is this where the problem resides? Thanks.

Comment: Your debugger output cannot be real. Both `buffer` and `temp` point to the same address and are of the same type, yet return different values. That's not possible. Please execute these again and provide the real output.

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) make sure you've allocated space for "buffer" before you read from your socket (!!!), and 2) check "errno".

Comment: UPDATE: You're reading your buffer ... into a local variable.  When the function terminates ... and buffer is now invalid!!!!   Bad, bad, bad!

Comment: @Codo it is real output. I guess it must be because of the `*buffer = temp` from `receivePacket`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void receivePacket(int *sock, char **buffer, long *tx, struct sockaddr_in *cliaddr) {
    //socket related code, initializations, etc.
    char temp[10] = { 0 };
    n = recvfrom(*sock, temp, 10, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cliAddr, &clilen);
    *buffer = temp;
}
```

`temp` is a local variable. It ceases to exist when the function returns, leaving `*buffer` pointing to some invalid place.

Comment: Oh, right that makes sense. Would you suggest a way to fix my code please?

Comment: Declare `buffer` in `main()` as a suitably sized array rather than a pointer, then use `strcpy()` in `receivePacket()`

Comment: You have 3 options: (1) do as @iharob suggest and malloc a buffer using strdup, or (2) make the `temp` static (giving up on thread safety), or (3) pass in a buffer from the calling code to `receivePacket`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is

```
char temp[10] = {0};
```

is a local variable, and it lives in the stack frame of the `receivePacket` function, try to copy it with `strdup` like

```
*buffer = strdup(temp);
```

when the `receivePacket` function returns the data in `temp` will no loger exists.

Also dont forget to `free(buffer)` after `strtol`.

And one more thing, either change

```
char temp[10] = {0};
```

to

```
char temp[11] = {0};
```

or

```
n = recvfrom(*sock, temp, 10, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cliAddr, &clilen);
```

to

```
n = recvfrom(*sock, temp, 9, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cliAddr, &clilen);
```

since otherwise you may overwrite the trailing `'\0'`, in which case `strdup` wont work, neither does `strtol`.

And you can also remove the `temp[10] = {0};` initialization and instead, after `recvfrom` just add

```
temp[n] = '\0';
```

Comment: I actually don't need to `free(buffer)` since it isn't dynamically allocated

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal you do if you use `strdup`.

Comment: Ah I understand, thanks. I ended up defining the array before calling `receivePacket` and passing in a pointer to use in `recvfrom`.